# Loop reddit bot to check for answers every 10 minutes

Tags: python, bots, reddit

I'm making a Reddit bot that goes through comments on certain subreddits and replies to those with certain keyphrases.

I originally did not have a loop, and it worked fine, but I had to click run again every few minutes. I am running my python script on pythonanywhere.com, using PRAW.

```py
import praw
import time

SECONDS_PER_MIN = 60
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('memes+dankmemes+comics+funny+pics')
keyphrase = ('Sauce+Sauce?')

def main():
    while True:
        for comment in subreddit.stream.comments():
            if keyphrase in comment.body:
                comment.reply('[Here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)\n\nI am a bot and this action was performed automatically. Learn more at [https://saucebot.com/](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)')
                print('Posted!')
                time.sleep(SECONDS_PER_MIN * 11)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expect it to respond to a random person who says "sauce" every 10 minutes, but now it won't respond to anyone.

Comment: Can you add the correct indentation to your code so it is easier to read?

Comment: as a side note, you should take a look at the Reddit rules against [spam](https://www.reddithelp.com/en/categories/rules-reporting/account-and-community-restrictions/what-constitutes-spam-am-i-spammer) before releasing your bot onto Reddit itself.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your script on a PC? You could potentially use the task scheduler for that without using python at all. Just save your script as a binary using [pyinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/PyInstaller/), then schedule it to run every ten minutes.